# XML Save/Export - SQL Server - Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014, export-to-xml

I am trying to export the xml generated from sql query. I am trying like this

```
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
 RECONFIGURE
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
 RECONFIGURE 
 EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @xml" -S <SERVERNAME> -D <DATABASE_NAME> -U <UserName> -P <PASSWORD> queryout "E:\test.xml" -T -c -t,'
```

while trying this I got the result listed below

```
 Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
 usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
 [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
 [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
 [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
 [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
 [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
 [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
 [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
 [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
 [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
 [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
 [-d database name]        [-K application intent]
```

I am not been able to find out the problem.

My questions are-

1. What I am doing wrong?
2. How to save/export xml in the file in drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this command:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @xml" -S <SERVERNAME> -D <DATABASE_NAME> -U <UserName> -P <PASSWORD> queryout "E:\test.xml" -T -c -t,
```

What I can tell you is immediately wrong:

- You are mixing authentication with -T and also -U -P
- Your query "select @xml" isn't valid

You could try something like:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select [test1]=1 for xml path" queryout e:\test.xml -T -c'
```

test.xml would look like:

```
 <row><test1>1</test1></row>
```

And build up to what kind of output you are looking for.

By default [`xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) executes on the server as the sql server service account, although a proxy account can be set up.

You might want to look into [`for xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to make sure you telling sql server how you want to xml to be formated.

References:

- [Import and Export Bulk Data by Using the bcp Utility (SQL Server) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [bcp Utility - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [xp_cmdshell - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)
- [For XML (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)
- [Using the Bulk-Load Tools in SQL Server - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html)